# React useState callback when updating in useEffect is not an option

Tags: reactjs

```
export default function App() {
  let editor;
  const [editorText, setEditorText] = useState("Type text");
  const [editorTextLength, setEditorTextLength] = useState("");

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setEditorText(editor.value);
    handleCursorChange();
  };

  const handleCursorChange = () => {
    setEditorTextLength(`${editorText.length}, ${editor.selectionStart}`);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{editorText}</p>
      <p>{editorTextLength}</p>
      <textarea
        ref={(tag) => (editor = tag)}
        className="App"
        onChange={handleEdit}
        onClick={handleCursorChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-napier-cbdpz?file=/src/App.js

In this simplified example, I am first setting `editorText` on `onChange` event, then deriving some value from both `editorText` and the cursor position on click. Then I'm setting that value as a state.

You can see that updating `editorText` value is lagging behind as you type into it. I think it's because `setEditorText` is async. However, React does not seem to provide a callback parameter or return a Promise from `setEditorText`.

I need to do this in the `onClick` handler, so doing it in `useEffect` is not an option.

How can I update these two states in a synchronous manner so `editorTextLength` updates after `editorText`? (I could directly access `editor.value` in this particular example, but let's pretend that's not an option)

Comment: Is this what you want https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-wu-sfopb ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use useRef() Hook

```
              import "./styles.css";
              import { useState } from "react";
              import React, { useRef } from "react";

              export default function App() {
                let editor;
                const [editorTextLength, setEditorTextLength] = useState("");

                const EditorText = useRef("Type text");

                const handleEdit = () => {
                  EditorText.current = editor.value
                  handleCursorChange();
                };

                const handleCursorChange = () => {
                  setEditorTextLength(`${EditorText.current.length}, ${editor.selectionStart}`);
                };

                return (
                  <>
                    <p>{EditorText.current}</p>
                    <p>{editorTextLength}</p>
                    <textarea
                      ref={(tag) => (editor = tag)}
                      className="App"
                      onChange={handleEdit}
                      onClick={handleCursorChange}
                    />
                  </>
                );
              }
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why this works and why mine doesn't?

Comment: Sorry I can't explain it to you my English are not that good I think somebody can explain it